# Why would 「行こうとしようよ」be interpreted as "let's try to try to go"?

Tags: grammar

> Your translation is single-volitional, not double. 「行こうとしようよ」 means
>   something like "Let's try to try going next week.", which is why it is
>   an incorrect answer.([source](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24190/acceptability-of-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-vs-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86))

It seems to be 行こうとする(to try to go) in the volitional form, so it would mean 'let's try to go' and not 'let's try to try to go'.

And since it is incorrect, how would we say "let's try" (with the nuance of ようとする and not with the one of てみる)?

Comment: I would like to know why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: "let's try" is translated as やってみよう. Does "let's try" with the nuance of ようとする make sense?

Comment: @YuuichiTam "より大きな利益を得ようとする" means "to try to gain a bigger profit" and it uses ようとする. If we say "Let's try to gain a bigger profit" it would be one of those cases where there is "let's try" with the "ようとする " nuance if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: I translated your sentence as より大きな利益を得ようと努力しましょう. This dictionary says "try" is also translated as 努力する. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/try+

Answer (score 1):

行こうとしようよ sounds slightly off. If you want to say “let’s try to go” you cd say 行ってみようよ. If for some reason your goal is to communicate an intention to *attempt to go* instead of actually just going (which puts us in metaphysical hair-splitting territory), then you cd say 行く努力をしよう but I have trouble imagining what context would require that (行ってみる努力ぐらいはしてくれてもいいだろう (“you could at least do me the favor of making the attempt to go”) or something?).

Answer (score 0):

行こうとしよう can mean something like "let's pretend to go" or an archaic way of saying "he will probably try to go".

Either way, that's out of question for the choice in the source.

As for translating "let's try", you could say 努力しよう、挑戦しよう、とりあえず やろう beside やってみよう, as the comment says.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you didn't talk about "how would we say "let's try" (with the nuance of ようとする and not with the one of てみる)?"